# rails activeadmin errors rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

my database is MongoDB and I use ActiveAdmin. 
before i add `gem 'activeadmin-mongoid', :git => 'git://github.com/simplybusiness/activeadmin-mongoid.git'` rspec pass every test with mongoDB, but after that rspec get an errors

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

file config/application.rb I repalce

> require all with
>
> require "action_controller/railtie"
>
> require "action_mailer/railtie"
>
> require "active_resource/railtie"
>
> require "sprockets/railtie"

I removed any activerecord config in folder config . I follow that [link](https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid#activeadminmongoid)

sorry about my bad english.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There have been several attempts to incorporate Mongo support within ActiveAdmin by third-party developers, but alas, no solid success yet. Progress on the official support can be followed at https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2714